# How can i see what is the current/live page in jquery-mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to find out what page is loaded in query mobile for a javascript script. I have been looking at: $.mobile.activePage but can't seem to work out how.

It would be good to have: `if($.mobile.activePage = "#page"){`

Comment: Is this question different than what I'm asking over in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503968/how-do-i-see-what-jquery-mobile-loaded-in-the-background ?

Comment: Yes, I needed to work out how to reference a page within javascript, you want to see the source-code without the query-mobile markup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$.mobile.activePage` returns a jQuery object. SO you should probably try something like this:

```
if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "page"){
```

Comment: Or $.mobile.activePage[0].id, which will be slightly quicker - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8440517/1040915

Answer (score 7):

You can get the currently active page by using `$.mobile.activePage`

If you want to test that a selected jQuery element is the current page you could look for the existence of the "ui-page-active" class:

```
if ($("#myPage").is(".ui-page-active")) { ... }
```