# How do I see what jQuery Mobile loaded in the background?

Tags: dom, jquery, jquery-mobile, javascript-framework

Using jQuery Mobile, I have seen how it adds to the existing DOM when links are clicked and a related page is served.  Then, when ready, it switches to that new `data-role="page"`.  But when I do a "view source" in the browser (Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox), I see the original page, as delivered, without the additional things loaded later (DOM injections).  How can I see what the browser really has (post-render HTML)?  If it happens to be a JavaScript solution, please don't presume I know where to put it and how to trigger it to show the content.

Comment: The "view source" feature in Chrome returns the HTML WITHOUT Javascript parse, so any DOM injections done in Javascript will not be display!

Comment: Gotta use the developer tools - Firebug for firefox, or Chrome's native dev tools. Inspect elements, it'll show the post-render HTML.

Comment: Mike, That looks answerish to me.  Wrench > Tools > Developer Tools would be a way to see the 'live' DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Chrome: Wrench > Tools > Developer Tools would be a way to see the 'live' DOM.