# How exactly does $.mobile.activePage property work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying something as follows,

```
$(document).bind ('pageshow', function (e, data) {
   console.log ($('#page_spots'));
   console.log ($.mobile.activePage);

   if ($.mobile.activePage == $('#page_spots')) { console.log ('Bingo!'); }
});
```

Being `#page_spots` a div with the attribute `data-role` set to `page`. In the example above, when the active page is `#page_spots` I want to log 'Bingo!' in the console.

I am a complete newbie to jQM and I don't know if this should be the right way or not.

Thank you in advance and apologies for my english.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get the active page's ID from `$.mobile.activePage` and compare it to a string rather than trying to compare to a jQuery object:

```
$(document).bind ('pageshow', function (e, data) {
   console.log ($('#page_spots'));
   console.log ($.mobile.activePage);

   if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'page_spots') { console.log ('Bingo!'); }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E6YuA/

`$.mobile.activePage` is nice to have because it is always a cached object of the current `data-role="page"` element that you can quickly reference.

**Update**

I was just reading this again and you don't need to use `.attr()` to find the ID, you can a bit more quickly by accessing the attribute directly from the DOMElement: `$.mobile.activePage[0].id`

Comment: Thanks Jasper! I can't accept your answer yet but I will within 2 minutes.